# Is there a soundtrack for No More Heroes 2?

Tags: no-more-heroes-2

Does anyone know if a soundtrack exists (official or unoffical) for No More Heroes 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [official sound track](http://suda51.wikia.com/wiki/No_More_Heroes_2:_Desperate_Struggle_Original_Soundtrack) does exist for No More Heroes 2: Desperate Struggle. It can be bought [here](http://ghm-store.com/?pid=24621580) from the Japanese publisher [Grasshopper Manufacture](http://www.grasshopper.co.jp/), though unfortunately it looks like they are out of stock (there were allegedly only 1000 copies pressed). After a somewhat thorough search of the intarwebs I was unable to locate any other retailers selling this soundtrack.

However, there are a number of third party rips available through direct download and torrenting. But as the legality of this varies from country to country and I'd rather not accidently link to a virus, you'll need to find these on your own.

In addition to the "official" soundtrack, a CD was included in the [Hoppers Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_More_Heroes_2:_Desperate_Struggle#Hoppers_Edition) of No More Heroes 2. However, it's [only 9 tracks](http://musicbrainz.org/release/18a90c78-0e97-4ecd-b3cb-07e97fb94f2d), compared to the 123 on the three-disc official release.